# How do you change directories using FtpWebRequest (.NET)?

Tags: .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Can someone tell me how to change directories using FtpWebRequest?  This seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but I'm not seeing it.

**EDIT**

I just want to add...I don't have my heart set on FtpWebRequest.  If there's a better (easier) way to do FTP in .NET please let me know.

---

Apparently there's no way to do it using a live connection, you need to change the uri to trick ftpwebrequest into using a different request (thanks Jon).

So I'm looking for a 3rd party client...

Some of the open source solutions I tried didn't work too well (kept crashing), but I found one open source solution that's passed some of my preliminary tests ([.NET FTP Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetftpclient/)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mariya/archive/2006/03/06/544523.aspx) from Mariya Atanasova which shows how you can fake it - basically you have to put the directory on the URL.

I suspect you may be better off with a dedicated FTP library though - one that doesn't try to force everything into the WebRequest way of doing things. I haven't personally used any 3rd party libraries for this, but a search for "FTP library .NET" finds lots of candidates.

---

#### Edit: jcolebrand (in case of 2006 blog linkrot possibility)

> Many customers ask us how they can use the CWD command with our FtpWebRequest.
>
> The answer is: you cannot use the command directly, but you can modify the uri parameter to achieve the same result.
>
> Let's say you're using the following format:

```
String uri = "ftp://myFtpUserName:myFtpUserPassword@myFtpUrl";
FtpWebRequest Request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
Request.Method = "LIST";
```

> The above example will bring you to your user's directory and list all the contents there. Now let's say you want to go 2 directories backwards and list the contents there (provided your user has permissions to do that). You close the previous FtpWebRequest and issue a new one with this uri

```
uri = "ftp://myFtpUserName:myFtpUserPassword@myFtpUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E";
```

> This is equivalent to logging in with your user's credentials and then using  `cd ../../`
>
> Note: if you try using the `”..”`  directly without escaping them the uri class will strip them, so `"ftp://myFtpUserName:myFtpUserPassword@myFtpUrl/../.."` is equivalent to `"ftp://myFtpUserName:myFtpUserPassword@myFtpUrl/"`
>
> Now let's say you want to go to another user's directory which is one level above the root. If you don't specify a user name and password it's equivalent to logging in as anonymous user. Then you issue a new `FtpWebRequest` with the following uri

```
"ftp://myFtpUrl/%2F/anotherUserDir"
```

> This is equivalent to logging in as anonymous and then doing

```
Cd /
cd anotherUserDirectory
```

Comment: I tried to open source libraries from codeproject and they were both giving me a ton of issues when connecting to a filezilla ftp server (don't know how well they work on iis ftp servers).  I guess I may have to buy a component.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Whatever client library you use, change to passive mode as soon as you can, assuming it gives you the option. That's much more likely to work through firewalls etc.

Comment: I'm finding a problem with the method described in the marked answer. The password we're using has an @ symbol in it, which causes the entire thing to fail.

Any FTP tools that allow first describing the destination directory and then the target file for uploading a file?

The problem is, of course, that the user is configured with a different home directory.

Answer (score 3):

You have to close the current connection:

```
request.Close();
```

And open a new one with an other uri:

```
uri = "ftp://example.com/%2F/directory" //Go to a forward directory (cd directory)
uri = "ftp://example.com/%2E%2E" //Go to the previously directory (cd ../)

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ListDirectory method of FTPWebRequest you can use ListDirectoryDetails method of FtpWebRequest .

From That you can use regular expression to get value you want.
Thats it,It work fine for me in my case