# Changing path to upload file in FTP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you change directories using FtpWebRequest (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330155/how-do-you-change-directories-using-ftpwebrequest-net)

```
    private void InitFTPTransfer(string filePath)
    {
        string[] ftpAddress = ddcdao.ddcAddress.Split(new string[] { "http://" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress[1] + "/root/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.SysFTPID, Properties.Settings.Default.SysFTPPassword);

        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();

    }
```

I have the above code to upload a particular file to a path.

Inside the ftp, how do I set a particular directory to upload the file on?

In this case, I'm uploading to a machine with embedded linux so it needs to be under /root/somedirectory

Edit: I've tried the suggestions of actually including the directory path in the request path but it just throws a System.Net.WebException with the message "System error" on the line of request.GetRequestStream();

Comment: @jcolebrand EMBEDDED linux, not windows

Comment: Ok, explain how my suggestion doesn't work? You obviously didn't say what you've tried already. Why does putting the path in the filename not work?

Comment: @jcolebrand It just throws a System.Net.WebException at "request.GetRequestStream()". Exception message is "System error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the directory in the request's path, i.e.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" 
                         + ddcdao.ddcAddress + "/" + someDirectory 
                         + "/" someFile);
```

Comment: I know, I realized that after about 15 minutes research on the request, but then I found Skeet's answer above and figured that was about as explicit as it got ... however, his could linkrot, I should edit that ..

Comment: hahahaha, I would've never liked to have faced this problem, I'm glad Skeet did. :p thanks for profile scanning ;-)