# Why i'm getting WebException on Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the method:

In this case i also use a f.TargetFolder the f.TargetFolder contain: ftpmytestdir

And the variable UploadPath contain:

ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/ftpmytestdir/clean_radar_image.png

Then it will do this line:

```
UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
```

After that UploadPath will be:

```
ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/ftpmytestdir/clean_radar_image.png
```

files is string[] type
For example in txf i have test.png

I saw the file size and everything there were no exceptions untill the Stream.

I used a breakpoint and moved untill line 78:

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
```

On this line it jumped to the catch area and show the exception.

```
private void StringArrayUploadFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string txf in files)
        {
            string fn = txf;
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
            string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(fn));
            if (!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = f.Passive;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Timeout = 300000;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
            long FileSize = new FileInfo(fn).Length;).Length;
            string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
            int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
            long SentBytes = 0;
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                    while (BytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (bw.CancellationPending)
                                return;

                            requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);

                            SentBytes += BytesRead;

                            string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                            bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                            if (NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                            {
                                fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                        BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                    }
                }
            }
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Status)
        {
            case WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure:
                ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";
                break;
            case WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                ConnectionError = "Error: Timout Request";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception message: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
       at FTP_ProgressBar.FtpProgress.StringArrayUploadFiles(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\FtpProgress.cs:line 78
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I found the problem but not sure how to solve it. U found that if f.TargetFolder contain a directory to upload the files to on the ftp for example myftptestdir then it's throwing the exception. But if f.TargetFolder is empty then it will upload the files fine but they will be uploaded to the root directory on the ftp. The problem is how to solve this when the f.TargetFolder have a directory inside.

Comment: I tried to add in the method the line: request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory; but still on the line using(Stream.... i'm getting the exception. Can't figure out why.

Comment: And i can create manualy directories on my ftp server so it's not a problem of acces previliages or something.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty clear from the exception--(550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

550 is an FTP error code indicating that the file is unavailable.  FTP isn't sophisticated enough to give more details than that.

Since I don't have access to the FTP server or the credentials used, and given that you are trying to *upload* a file, not download, I'm guessing that the account you're using doesn't have write rights on the server, so you can't create the file.  It's also possible that the filename is invalid for some reason.

A good test in situations like this is to use the same credentials to perform the same operation using a 3rd party interactive FTP program.

Comment: I found the problem but not sure how to solve it. U found that if f.TargetFolder contain a directory to upload the files to on the ftp for example myftptestdir then it's throwing the exception. But if f.TargetFolder is empty then it will upload the files fine but they will be uploaded to the root directory on the ftp. The problem is how to solve this when the f.TargetFolder have a directory inside.

Comment: They seem to be doing the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330155/how-do-you-change-directories-using-ftpwebrequest-net but they have it working. Are you sure the folder name has / instead of \?  Are you trying to create multiple sub folders at the same time (unlikely to work).

Comment: t's working now i had to create first the directory to upload to then to upload the files. I created new method to create the directory first. And now everything is working. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Marking this as the correct answer would be appreciated.